# ASP.NET site slow during postback only in IE browser

Tags: asp.net, performance, iis, ssl, https

We have an ASP.NET web forms application hosted in Rackspace. We have a weird problem for the past three weeks, that the post back is responding very slow in Internet explorer sporadically. But, the issue doesn't occur in non IE browsers like Chrome, firefox. Also, when the HTTPS traffic is decrypted using Fiddler, the postback works fine in IE itself.

HTTPS postback from IE browser takes more than a minute to reach the server.

Any reason why the request takes so long to reach the server from IE browser?

Comment: When using Internet Explorer F12 tools, how large is the total page size?  Also.. is this behavior on your machine, or can you reproduce on other PC's as well?

Comment: This question appears to belong on another site in the Stack Exchange network because its not about programming. Perhaps [Super User](https://www.superuser.com/) or [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/).